# Colored fancy boxes

Tags: color, boxes, backgrounds

I am trying to produce some fancy boxes. I have found the `fancybox` package that does the boxes I want.

What I can't find now is: How do I change their background color?

I would also like to make the box occupy the whole `\textwidth`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean the `fancybox` (not `fancyboxes`) package? It does not support colors by itself.

I would use the `framed` package together with `xcolor` to define the fancy box you want. If you do not require special stuff like `verbatim` material you could simply go with:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
% ...
\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
   \color{<text color>}%
   <text>
}}
```

Otherwise define an own `framed` environment. Then the box will be `\textwidth` wide by itself. It even support page break, i.e. splits over multiple pages if the internal text does.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{myfancybox}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}}%
  \color{<text color>}\MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did meant `fancybox`. I have managed what I wanted with the `sectionbox` package. Does `framed` allow for `shadowbox`?

Comment: @Tiago: It support all boxing macros. Just redefine `\FrameCommand` accordantly.

Answer (score 6):

use package [mdframed](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) the boxes can also have a pagebreak inside

Comment: The link is broken, here is one that works (for now) http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf

Answer (score 4):

For those who are (almost) complete beginners and want something they can directly use I stumble upon the "tcolorbox" package, here is a tutorial

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf