# Defining my own "boxes"?

Tags: macros, boxes

What I want is a environment that lets me create my own "boxes" (or blocks? I keep confusing them...) with the following properties

1. They visually couple together a piece of sourcecode and a explanation, possibly a mathematical formula
2. They get indexed and named somehow so I can list them in a central directory somewhere

To get a feeling for what I want to place in the box:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C++,basicstyle=\small]{fragments/leda-math-linear-solver.cpp}
\begin{equation}matrix * (x * x\_factor) = right\end{equation}
```

So its basicly a `\lstinputlisting` and a `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` I want to glue together. But I would prefer not to get nailed into the equation too much, as I might want to use some other explanation then a equation for some piece of sourcecode.

I did a few attempts to solve 1) by kidding around with answers I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/colored-fancy-boxes), especially the mdframed package. But how would I define my own command to avoid repeating the style markup over and over again?

For 2) I thought about piggybacking the theorem system. Would that be a viable way to go?

(And sorry for maybe badly mixing up latex terminology. I am currently in the process of learning the benefits of the whole system by taking a deep jump into it and holding on to everything that seems useful to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\jobname.tex` with your cpp example file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Example}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Examples}

\newcommand\myExa[3][]{%
\lstinputlisting[language=C++,basicstyle=\small,#1]{#2}
  #3}
\begin{document}

\myExa[label=foo,caption=foobar]{\jobname.tex}{%
  \begin{equation}matrix * (x * x\_factor) = right\end{equation}}

\myExa[label=bar,caption=foobarbaz]{\jobname.tex}{%
  \begin{quotation}Some nonsense text here\end{quotation}}

as shown in Example~\ref{foo} and in Example~\ref{bar} \ldots

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, so this introduces the new command `myExa` with 3 parameters? The first argument given is in the []-brackets, the second is the name of the file and the third the explanation in whichever format I desire?

And I guess the label part allows the indexing? But how does `\lstlistoflistings` know how to only list my pieces of sourcecode?

Comment: @Marcus: with `\myExa[nolol,..]{...` =>nolistOflistings. And there are also `linerange=...-...`

Comment: I meant something different: Suppose I would also introduce JAVA listings, how could I tell `\lstlistoflistings` to create one list of my JAVA and one list of my C++ samples?

Comment: @Marcus: then you have to define another listcounter and maybe a `\myJavaExa` which does a `refstepcounter`. See package `float` how an own list can be defined.